# compare the length of two list and append in racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I've tried to write a function, merge_longer, in Racket that takes as input two lists, L1 and L2. If L1 is longer than L2 the function appends L2 to L1. Otherwise, it appends L1 to L2.

```
(define L1 '(4 6 8 9))
(define L2 '(1 2 3)) 
(define (merge_longer L1 L2) (if (> length(L1) length(L2)) (append L1 L2)(append L2 L1)))  
(merge_longer L1 L2)
```

However, this error is displayed while I run it:
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(4 6 8 9)
  arguments...: [none]

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.

```
(define (merge-longer l1 l2)
  (if (> (length l1) (length l2))
      (append l1 l2)
      (append l2 l1)))
```

Note that you can add extra parentheses in Racket.
When you write (l1) it means "apply the function l1 to no arguments".
Since l1 is a list, not a function, you get an error.